Uniqueness results that follow from CH
Recently, Joel David Hamkins presented a historical thought experiment that shows that CH could have been adopted as an axiom if we had been using the hyperreal field $\mathbb{R}^*$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ in calculus, since we'd like to have a categoricity result for $\mathbb{R}^*$ in this alternative history.
Regardless of the validity of this argument, which I am not planning to discuss here, I thought it would be nice to have a collection of uniqueness results that follow from CH, not to claim that CH should be an axiom but simply to have such a list for its own sake. There seems to be no similar question on MO as far as I can tell. Therefore, my big-list question is:

What are some uniqueness results (whose negations are believed/known
to be relatively consistent with ZFC) that follow from CH?


For a balanced answer :-) you should also look into uniqueness results from forcing axioms in places where CH gives monstrous variety.

@AndrésE.Caicedo I am unsure whether you have in mind actual such results where CH gives monstrous variety? To what would you refer?

@JoelDavidHamkins A typical example is the classification of $\aleph_1$-dense sets of reals of size $\aleph_1$.

An example would be the uniqueness of the asymptotic cone for uniform lattices in $SL_m(\mathbb R)$. Under $\neg CH$, these admit $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ non-homeomorphic asymptotic cones.
See 
Asymptotic cones of finitely presented groups, by Linus Kramer, Saharon Shelah, Katrin Tent and Simon Thomas.

Under CH, we have saturated models of size continuum of any consistent first-order theory in a countable language, and for a complete theory these are unique by the back-and-forth method.
(In my paper, I had pointed out that the CH is actually equivalent to the assertion that there is a unique smallest countably saturated real-closed field.)

Incidentally, when one has a CH-guaranteed isomorphism $\phi$ between two distinct ultrapowers of type $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}/\mathcal F$, is there any chance $\phi$ might preserve the internal subsets?

Yes, because the models are saturated in the language that includes constants for every real, so the isomorphism will make a commutative diagram with the elementary embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}/\mathcal{F}$.

I am not sure I follow.  An infinite internal subset always contains nonstandard elements, so it can't be a subset of $\mathbb R$.

In model-theoretic approaches to NSA, there are three types of sets: (M1) *-transforms of "real" sets, (M2) internal sets; (M3) external sets.  In axiomatic approaches to NSA, there are two types of sets: (A1) standard sets; (A2) nonstandard sets.  Here (A1) and (A2) correspond to (M1) and (M2) (there is no counterpart for external sets).  Thus, a singleton consisting of a nonstandard integer is of type (M2) or (A2) depending on which framework your are working in.  An uniform infinitesimal partition is another.

If you are using higher sets in NSA, as I believe you usually do, then CH will not be enough to get saturation, and one doesn't generally even get categoricity for that case.

Without preserving internal sets, there may not be much significance to the uniqueness of the isomorphism type of ${}^\ast\mathbb R$, because internal sets are the bread and butter of NSA, and they are the ones to which the transfer principle applies.  If so, such "categoricity" would apparently not be very useful.

I don't really agree. When using infinitesimals in calculus, most of the benefit for the main theory arises already when concerned merely with functions and predicates on the reals $\mathbb{R}$, and the nonstandard analogues $f^$ for the ordinary functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $A^$ for $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

But let me add that with the GCH, one gets saturated models in every uncountable regular cardinality, this will provide the desired categoricity results for the higher-order structures.

Namely, the internal sets you mention, for ultrapowers, are just those arising in the higher-order structure $P(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{N}}/\mathcal{F}$, but one will not generally achieve saturation for such a large structure using only an ultrapower indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, even with CH. But meanwhile, under the GCH there are indeed saturated models elementarily extending $P(\mathbb{R})$, and one can achieve this with larger ultrapowers.

Assuming $\textsf{CH}$, a lot of natural fourth-order functionals are computationally equivalent (Kleene's S1-S9) to $\exists^3$.  These equivalences do not seem to go through without the former.   ([1])
[1] Dag Normann and Sam Sanders, The computational properties of the Axiom of Choice, Journal of Logic and Computation, 2022.

Here's one about my favorite topological space, the Stone–Čech remainder of the natural numbers, denoted $\mathbb N^*$ or $\omega^*$. The characterization is due to Parovicenko.

Assuming CH, $\mathbb N^*$ is the unique compact Hausdorff zero-dimensional space such that (1) there is a basis of size $\mathfrak c$, (2) every nonempty $G_\delta$ has infinite interior, and (3) it is an $F$-space (disjoint open $F_\sigma$'s have disjoint closures).

Let me note that $\mathbb N^*$ always has these properties. But only under CH is it the only space with these properties. In other words, this description of $\mathbb N^*$ characterizes it uniquely if and only if CH holds. This was proved by van Douwen and van Mill in
van Douwen, Eric K.; van Mill, Jan, Parovicenko’s characterization of (\beta\omega -\omega) implies CH, Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 72, 539-544 (1978). ZBL0393.54004.
Via Stone duality, this can also be used to obtain a description of the Boolean algebra $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)/\mathrm{Fin}$ that characterizes it completely under CH. This is somewhat related to Joel's answer, by the way, because the uniqueness result for $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)/\mathrm{Fin}$ can be proved via saturation.

In line with Joel’s answer, we have all sorts of uniqueness of ultrapower results that follow form CH and whose negations are known to be consistent with ZFC. Since classical model theory is not my area, I’ll let others add those examples. For me, I’ll point out an example in my field: For any separable (or, more generally, of density character less than or equal to continuum, under the $\sigma$-strong topology) II$_1$ factor $M$ (i.e., an infinite-dimensional tracial von Neumann algebra with scalars as its center), its ultrapower $M^\mathcal{U}$ is independent of the choice of free ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ iff CH holds.
